# Showing a process is a markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $P$ be a stochastic $N \times N$ matrix. We consider two *independent copies* of a Markov process on $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ with transition probabilities given by $P$. Both are assumed to start deterministically at state $1$.

> The two processes can be thought of as a single process on $\{1,\ldots,N\}^2$. Is this a markov process? What does the transition matrix look like?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a Markov process, on a new state space like you mentioned: $N^2$.
What should be the transmission matrix? assuming every step in each chain is independent in the other, the probability of moving from $(n_1, n_2)$ to $(m_1, m_2)$ is the probability of moving in the first chain from $n_1$ to $m_1$, and the same idea in the other chain.
By assumption, the requested probability will be ${[P]}^{n_1}_{m_1} \cdot {[P]}^{n_2}_{m_2}$.